# ASP.NET Profiling

Tags: asp.net, profiling

I have a slow asp.net program running. I would like to profile the production server to see what is going on, but I don't want to slow down the production server noticeably.

In general, is it standard practice to profile a production box or just local dev boxes? Also, what progams do you recommend to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4):

I can recommend you to use "[dynatrace Ajax edition 3](http://ajax.dynatrace.com/ajax/en/)" for client side profiling (it's free and easy tool) and "[JetBrains dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/)" for server side profiling. This tools does not slow down server as i know.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Tracing` and it is recommended to check these things on your local machine, but if you want to check something on server, you can enable tracing for short in your web.config.

> ASP.NET tracing enables you to view diagnostic information about a single request for an ASP.NET page. ASP.NET tracing enables you to follow a page's execution path, display diagnostic information at run time, and debug your application. ASP.NET tracing can be integrated with system-level tracing to provide multiple levels of tracing output in distributed and multi-tier applications.

[ASP.NET Tracing Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386420.aspx)

[Tracing in ASP.NET](https://web.archive.org/web/20210324184141/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/081501-1.shtml)

Answer (score 2):

I guess the answer is really 'it depends'! I would start by considering whether the program runs slowly just on the production server, or whether it runs slowly on a development environment as well. I would also consider how closely I could get my development/test environment to match the production environment.

Once you've done that, consider whether there are any areas that could represent obvious bottlenecks that you might be able to eliminate. So, for example, is the ASP.NET application backed by some form of database? If it is, you can monitor the performance of the database separately and establish whether that is where the problem lies.

Next, try and be very specific about what you mean by 'slow performance'. Is it consistently slow (compared to what?), or just when you do specific actions. This may give you another clue as to where your problem lies, or at least what questions you should be asking.

Having answered lots of these questions, I'd then bust out [ANTS Performance Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/) to try and profile what's going on. It has a fairly minimal overhead when profiling an application, and you should only really be running it for a fairly short time anyway, as you'll hopefully by this point have more specific questions you want to answer, or specific actions that you want to dig into.

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is Prefix (http://www.prefix.io). It will let you see all of your SQL queries, logs, HTTP calls, and a lot more.

Another option is Glimpse or the Mini profiler.