# Firebug Net Waiting time

Tags: debugging, firebug

Does this include the total time it took for request to come back? If not, please define exactly what Waiting means in the context of firebug net tab.

I am using asp.net mvc and would like to track down where my delay between the server and client really happens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Waiting" (in purple) denotes the amount of time your server spent crunching, that is, the amount of time between the request being fully sent and the response beginning.  The time it took for the response to come back is shown by "Receiving" (in green).

My rule has been this: when the "Waiting" time is high, profile your server-side code for possible bottlenecks.  When the "Receiving" time is high, see about gzipping your responses or otherwise reducing the response payload.

Comment: my dilemma right now is that the server code is super fast but the waiting time is high.

Comment: I see. I do believe your problem lies on the server side, but perhaps the bottleneck is not your code. Profiling is in order here. As you can see I'm very new here, so I'm not sure that discussing profiling would stray too off-topic for the rules. I'll just say that something in your server-side stack is most likely the issue here. If you provide more information about your environment (perhaps in another question?), I'm sure I and others could suggest good ways to track down the culprit.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11583679/asp-net-mvc-and-ajax-added-performance-overhead

Comment: by profiling what do you mean? is that a tool, or simple debugging?

Comment: There are profiling tools, yes ([SO thread on the subject](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912994/asp-net-profiling)), but it can be as simple as measuring the time between different method calls in your code to try and isolate a time-consuming one (if the problem lies in your code).  Profiling simply means determining what parts of your code are costly in terms of performance.

Comment: oh I did this already. My server code is fast. I suspect it's server settings and/or network issues.

Comment: if your Waiting time is long, it might be because of network and your server hosting. And in this case you can't do anything. For example, in my case, if I open page from USA - waiting time is 40ms, and if I open it from Europe - waiting time is 200 ms. Apparently, I can't do anything with my server side code to reduce this time.