# How do I Identify the exact code that causes High cpu usage on my site?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-applications, nopcommerce

I have a nopcommerce Website and sometimes it during a campaign We get around 300 concurrent users. The CPU reaches 99 & 100% level with a configuration of 40 CPU & 160 GB RAM. RAM usage is less than 15 GB on it because DB is not too heavy.

I am not a programmer and I want to figure out what exactly is causing this CPU spike. How can I determine this.

I have found that IIS is causing the spike but not able to find out which particular piece of code is creating problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can use profiler programs to measure how long a method takes to complete or at a given instant how much memory is used etc. We are using [JetBrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/products.html?fromMenu#lang=csharp) tools. Please have a look at dotTreace and dotMemory.

Comment: See also:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912994/asp-net-profiling

Comment: I downloaded JEtbrains and install it on the server. I attached it with a IIS Default Pool and I see a list of threads that just dont give me sufficient information about the code.

Comment: @milanm Choose your profiler options such as Sampling, Timeline etc. Then attach it to w3wp. Then actually put some stress onto your server as if it is being used. Call APIs etc. Then click get snapshot. You will see alot of info at the result

Comment: @EmrahSüngü, Can you help us by having a look with an anydesk session? We can hire your services as as freelance consultant if this session turns out to be productive.

Comment: @milanm, I would love to help you on a remote session but unfortunately I am at the office right now, So i can not remote assist you :/ If you want I can step-by-step you on StackOverFlow chat

Answer (score 0):

Debug, see which line(s) take long to execute.

If you're not familiar with debugging you will probably need a programmer to do it!

You could however speed up the process by identifying which part of your site takes a while to load or play around the site whilst watching the CPU in task manager and see which point it spikes, this would help a programmer to narrow down which methods they need to look at.

Answer (score -2):

use below code to get total memory

```
long memoryUses = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
```

When you found, your memory is too high then run the forcefully garbage collector.

```
System.GC.Collect()
```

Hope your problem will be resolve after this.

Comment: Question for CPU spike, not memory

Comment: This is a bad idea for a number of reasons. Your memory being high can be a good thing ultimately if you're employing an aggressive caching strategy. Additionally, the overload you're suggesting is going to run *all generations*. The role of the garbage collector is to delay Gen 2 collections, so you definitely don't want to arbitrarily cause Gen 2 collections. Etc.

Get to the cause of your GC issues by identifying what's causing excessive allocations.